# Why nothing in the output file for mapreduce matrix and vector multiplication?

Tags: javascript, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I'm trying to multiply a 1000x1000 matrix with a 1000x1 vector by mapreduce. The input file shown as the picture was made of random single digit variables and split by a space.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4r02.png)

My code is as following:

```js
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
 
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;
 
public class Matrix_Vector {
 

    public static class MatrixMapper extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        private String flag = null;// name of the data set
        private int rowNum = 1000;// row of matrix A
        private int colNum = 1;//cols of matrix B (for vector is one)
        private int rowIndexA = 1; // row index of matrix A
        private int rowIndexB = 1; // row index of matrix B
 
        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            flag = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();// Get the file name
        }
 
        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] tokens = value.toString().split(" ");
            if ("matrix".equals(flag)) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= colNum; i++) {
                    Text k = new Text(rowIndexA + "," + i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++) {
                        Text v = new Text("a," + (j + 1) + "," + tokens[j]);
                        context.write(k, v);
                    }
                }
                rowIndexA++;// move to next line
            } else if ("vector".equals(flag)) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= rowNum; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < tokens.length; j++) {
                        Text k = new Text(i + "," + (j + 1));
                        Text v = new Text("b," + rowIndexB + "," + tokens[j]);
                        context.write(k, v);
                    }
                }
                rowIndexB++;// move to next line
            }
        }
    }

 

    public static class MatrixReducer extends
            Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Map<String, String> mapA = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Map<String, String> mapB = new HashMap<String, String>();
 
            for (Text value : values) {
                String[] val = value.toString().split(",");
                if ("a".equals(val[0])) {
                    mapA.put(val[1], val[2]);
                } else if ("b".equals(val[0])) {
                    mapB.put(val[1], val[2]);
                }
            }
 
            int result = 0;
            Iterator<String> mKeys = mapA.keySet().iterator();
            while (mKeys.hasNext()) {
                String mkey = mKeys.next();
                if (mapB.get(mkey) == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                result += Integer.parseInt(mapA.get(mkey))
                        * Integer.parseInt(mapB.get(mkey));
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(result));
        }
    }

 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        //job start running
        long main_start=System.currentTimeMillis();

        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) 
        {
          System.err.println("Usage: MatrixVector <in> <out>");
          System.exit(2);
        }
  
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Matrix_Vector");
        job.setJarByClass(Matrix_Vector.class);
        
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        
        job.setMapperClass(MatrixMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MatrixReducer.class);
      
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
     
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        if (job.waitForCompletion(true)) { 
               long main_end=System.currentTimeMillis();      
               System.out.println("The process is end");
               System.out.println("Time of running is "+ " :  "+(main_end - main_start) +"  ms");
               System.exit(0);
           }else {
               System.out.println("The process ended with false");
           }

    }
}
```

And this is the result I got and I have one success file and one output file in my output path but there's nothing in the output file and also seen from the "Bytes Written=0". I cannot find where my code logic went wrong and sorry for the result shown as code format, I'm still learning how to do better post.

```html
21/03/26 08:05:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1616694898641_0007 completed successfully
21/03/26 08:05:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=6
                FILE: Number of bytes written=606314
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=2002216
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
                HDFS: Number of read operations=9
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=2
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Data-local map tasks=2
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=102529
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=13848
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=102529
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=13848
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=102529
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=13848
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=104989696
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=14180352
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=2000
                Map output records=0
                Map output bytes=0
                Map output materialized bytes=12
                Input split bytes=212
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=0
                Reduce shuffle bytes=12
                Reduce input records=0
                Reduce output records=0
                Spilled Records=0
                Shuffled Maps =2
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=2
                GC time elapsed (ms)=658
                CPU time spent (ms)=4140
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=519413760
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=6241820672
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=263872512
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=2002004
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=0
The process is end
Time of running is  :  182011  ms
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Wen

Comment: Have you had a chance to debug or just use some test prints on the console to be logged (all `System.out.println()` commands are logged under `{hadoop_dir}/logs/userlogs` for each job in a number of instances)? Because with a quick first glance there might be some kind of  problem within the Map functions, since the system output says `Map output records=0` and `Map output bytes=0`.

Comment: Hello Coursal, thank you for reply! Yes I think the map function was wrong too but cannot find the bug in the loop logic. Thanks for the advice, truly helpful! One question tho is it possible I just run this in the eclipse? Or I have to do in the hadoop command?

Comment: Hello Coursal, I tried the test print but in my log folder there are 5 files: syslog, stdout, stderr, prelaunch.out, prelaunch.err. Both stdout and prelaunch.err are empty and none of them prints what I wrote to print , including the 1st step - importing the file and print the file name

Comment: About how to run the project, it doesn't really matter as long as you have correctly added all the Hadoop modules through Maven. Running through the hadoop bash commands is always safer, though. As for the log files, because the `stdout` appeared empty, this must mean that none of the `context.write` commands are executed, which in that case means that the mapper's input somehow don't match any of the `if`, `else if` cases. That's probably why none of the commands are executed in both of these blocks in the Map function

Comment: Hello Coursal, thank you for replying! I think I figured out where went wrong, the file name should include .txt